# getting exception in maven after creating restful client

Tags: java, apache, rest, maven, cxfrs

i am using apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2 server and  created the restful client in java using this bellow line

```
Response response = WebClient.create("localhost:8080/test).path("/change/event").post(userdata);
```

i included following dependency in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
</dependency>
```

now compilation is success but when i deploy using mvn tomee:deploy then i am getting the foollowing exception 
localhost log file: http://www.docdroid.net/6snb/localhost-log.txt.html
catalina log file:http://www.docdroid.net/6sne/cataline-log.txt.html

i do not know which dependency has problem and here my pom.xml file
http://www.docdroid.net/6soc/mypom.txt.html

the catalina log file.

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.setupFactory(AbstractJAXRSFactoryBean.java:320)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean.create(JAXRSServerFactoryBean.java:163)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deploy(CxfRsHttpListener.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.rs.CxfRsHttpListener.deployPojo(CxfRsHttpListener.java:110)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.deployPojo(RESTService.java:436)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.rest.RESTService.afterApplicationCreated(RESTService.java:248)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxRsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxRsService.java:51)
    ... 78 more

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalProxy is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass0(Proxy.java:484)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:713)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.createThreadLocalProxy(InjectionUtils.java:875)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.AbstractResourceInfo.addContextMethod(AbstractResourceInfo.java:163)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.AbstractResourceInfo.checkContextMethod(AbstractResourceInfo.java:146)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.AbstractResourceInfo.findContextSetterMethods(AbstractResourceInfo.java:132)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.AbstractResourceInfo.(AbstractResourceInfo.java:65)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.ProviderInfo.(ProviderInfo.java:29)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.initJaxbProviders(ProviderFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.(ProviderFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.getInstance(ProviderFactory.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory.(ProviderFactory.java:71)
    ... 85 more

Comment: Posting things on an external site usually blocks anyone behind a corporate firewall/proxy from being able to answer you. Post the relevant bits right here for the best chance of getting help.

Comment: check now catalina log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use provided scope as a dependency in pom.xml. then it will work.e.g

```
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
<version>2.6.4</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

use scope provided.